# Setting my Contact form to auto-fill from the Company ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

On my Contact#new form I have a drop down which gets all the company names and sorts them a-z,
when Im on my company#show page and I click new contact, somehow I want rails to autofill the contact#new drop down in the form with the company which I came from, is there a way to do this?

My contact `belongs_to :company`
My company `has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy`

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :company_id %><br />
    <%= f.select(:company_id, Company.all.collect {|company| [company.name, company.id]}.sort{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}, :prompt => "Select a Company") %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize new object with `company_id` filled, like this
in the controller:

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new(:company_id => params[:company_id])
end
```

and then in the view:

```
form_for @contact do |f|
...
```

and in the `link_to` show the form you need to have this path:

```
link_to "Add new contact", new_contact_path(:company_id => @company.id)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks it worked nicely but is there anyway, after I click submit and when the page refresh's it does not remove the company from the drop down.

Comment: after submit you get to create action and then redirected to where?

Comment: hmm should still be there in this case. Actually it would be better to move instantiation to controller, probably the data will be kept. i've modified the answer